# Does Delphi's static keyword have any point in native-only code?

Tags: delphi, oop, class

My understanding is that the `static` keyword was introduced for compatibility with .NET (along with `strict`)

```
class TExample
  class procedure First;
  class procedure Second; static;
```

The differences between procedures `First` and `Second` are :-

1. `First` can be overridden in a descendant class
2. `First` passes an implicit self parameter referencing the `TExample` class.

Class procedure `Second` cannot be overridden and passes no parameters and is thus .NET compatible. So is there any point in using the `static` keyword in native-only code now that there is a divergence between Delphi & Prism syntax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Static class methods have no hidden class reference argument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Static_Methods). Because of this, they are assignment compatible with plain old function pointers, and can therefore be used for interaction with the Windows API and other C APIs. Example:

```
type
  TForm = class
  private
    class function NonStaticWndProc (wnd: HWND; Message: Cardinal;
      wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
    class function StaticWndProc (wnd: HWND; Message: Cardinal;
      wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; static;
    procedure RegisterClass;
  end;

procedure TForm.RegisterClass;
type
  TWndProc = function (wnd: HWND; Message: Cardinal;
    wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
var
  WP: TWndProc;
  WindowClass: WNDCLASS;
begin
  //WP := NonStaticWndProc; // doesn't work
  WP := StaticWndProc; // works
  // ...
  TWndProc (WindowClass.lpfnWndProc) := WP;
  Windows.RegisterClass (WindowClass);
end;
```

(Of course, you could have used a global function instead, but other than global functions, static class functions have a clear association with a class.)

Answer (score 4):

with static, it is a little bit faster. There's one `add esp, -8` in method First which is not there in Second.

```
program staticTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TExample=class
    class procedure First;
    class procedure Second; static;
  end;


{ TExample }

class procedure TExample.First;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  i:=61374;
end;

class procedure TExample.Second;
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  i:=44510;
end;

begin
  { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Hier Code einfügen }
  TExample.First;
  TExample.Second;
end.
```

First:

```
staticTest.dpr.20: begin
00408474 55               push ebp
00408475 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
00408477 83C4F8           add esp,-$08  ;This is the line I mentioned
0040847A 8945FC           mov [ebp-$04],eax
staticTest.dpr.21: i:=61374;
0040847D C745F8BEEF0000   mov [ebp-$08],$0000efbe
staticTest.dpr.22: end;
00408484 59               pop ecx
00408485 59               pop ecx
00408486 5D               pop ebp
00408487 C3               ret
```

Second:

```
staticTest.dpr.27: begin
00408488 55               push ebp
00408489 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0040848B 51               push ecx
staticTest.dpr.28: i:=44510;
0040848C C745FCDEAD0000   mov [ebp-$04],$0000adde
staticTest.dpr.29: end;
00408493 59               pop ecx
00408494 5D               pop ebp
00408495 C3               ret 
00408496 8BC0             mov eax,eax
```

In short - I see no reason.

Comment: The thing is that the first one saves eax. Probably some hardcoded prologue in the compiler. IOW the first apparantly has a parameter and the second not. It might reduce to the same with optimization on though.